# Adding toml config file into helm chart

Tags: templates, kubernetes, telegraf, configmap, toml

Newbie at Helm here. I'm trying to add static .toml config file into a helm chart, but the content of deployed manifest bothers me, here's the tree of my chart.

```
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── telegraf.conf
└── templates
    └── configmap.yaml
```

configmap.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: telegraf-api
data:
  {{ (.Files.Glob "telegraf.conf").AsConfig | indent 4 }}
```

telegraf.conf

```
[global_tags]
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = "0s"
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false
[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = true
  totalcpu = true
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false
  core_tags = false
[[inputs.disk]]
  ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs", "iso9660", "overlay", "aufs", "squashfs"]
[[inputs.diskio]]
[[inputs.kernel]]
[[inputs.mem]]
[[inputs.processes]]
[[inputs.swap]]
[[inputs.system]]
```

I can install the chart without any problems, but the problem occurs when i inspect deployed manifest (it has a lot of backslashes like this):

```
$ helm get manifest telegraf
---
# Source: telegraf/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: telegraf-api
data:
      telegraf.conf: "[global_tags]\n[agent]\n  interval = \"10s\"\n  round_interval = true\n
      \ metric_batch_size = 1000\n  metric_buffer_limit = 10000\n  collection_jitter =
      \"0s\"\n  flush_interval = \"10s\"\n  flush_jitter = \"0s\"\n  precision = \"0s\"\n
      \ hostname = \"\"\n  omit_hostname = false\n[[inputs.cpu]]\n  percpu = true\n  totalcpu
      = true\n  collect_cpu_time = false\n  report_active = false\n  core_tags = false\n[[inputs.disk]]\n
      \ ignore_fs = [\"tmpfs\", \"devtmpfs\", \"devfs\", \"iso9660\", \"overlay\", \"aufs\",
      \"squashfs\"]\n[[inputs.diskio]]\n[[inputs.kernel]]\n[[inputs.mem]]\n[[inputs.processes]]\n[[inputs.swap]]\n[[inputs.system]]\n
      \ "
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to deploy it so the config don't get messed up?

Comment: Without looking too carefully, I'm guessing the output is correct – if you load it with a YAML parser you'll get the original file content, and if you mount the ConfigMap into a Pod it will have the correct file.  Are you actually getting incorrect file content?

Answer (score 0):

This should not cause any issues with the configuration. The backslashes in the configuration file are used to indicate that the line should be continued on the next line. When the configmap is loaded to pod, actual key-value pairs will be correctly loaded.